# Populate list recursively with lapply in R

Tags: r, lapply

I am struggling to populate a pre-defined 3-level nested list.

```
lst <- lapply(list("A1"=NULL, "B1"=NULL),
              function(x){
                 lapply(list("Level2"=NULL),
                        function(y){
                            list("Level3"=NULL)})})

str(lst)
List of 2
 $ A1:List of 1
  ..$ Level2:List of 1
  .. ..$ Level3: NULL
 $ B1:List of 1
  ..$ Level2:List of 1
  .. ..$ Level3: NULL
```

Now, let's say we would like to replace every 3rd level by concatenating the names of the parent levels in order to get:

```
str(lst)
List of 2
 $ A1:List of 1
  ..$ Level2:List of 1
  .. ..$ Level3: "A1///Level2"
 $ B1:List of 1
  ..$ Level2:List of 1
  .. ..$ Level3: "B1///Level2"
```

Doing like follows drops the 2nd level names and disorganise the initial list structure:

```
lst[] <- lapply(names(lst),
                function(x){
                    lapply(names(lst[[x]]),
                           function(y){
                               lst[[x]][[y]][["Level3"]] <- paste(x, y, sep="///")
                           }
                    )
                }
         )

str(lst)
List of 2
 $ A1:List of 1
  ..$ : chr "A1///Level2"
 $ B1:List of 1
  ..$ : chr "B1///Level2"
```

I am pretty sure it is a basic task, but I don't see why it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have replaced element `Level3` of the second level of lists with a character vector, which used to be a list.

To get around this problem, just wrap your `paste` function in `list`:

Additionally, the problem with using `lapply` on the names of an object is that the results are not named as the original object. You can use `setNames` from base R to get around that, but unfortunately, you have to do it at every level:

```
lst <- setNames(lapply(names(lst),
                function(x){
                    setNames(lapply(names(lst[[x]]),
                           function(y){
                               setNames(lst[[x]][[y]][["Level3"]] <- list(paste(x, y, sep="///")), "Level3")
                           }
                    ), names(lst[[x]]))
                }
         ), names(lst))
str(lst)
#List of 2
# $ A1:List of 1
#  ..$ Level2:List of 1
#  .. ..$ Level3: chr "A1///Level2"
# $ B1:List of 1
#  ..$ Level2:List of 1
#  .. ..$ Level3: chr "B1///Level2"
```

Comment: Not very convenient indeed, although it works well. `lapply` does not seem to be the right tool for this task.

Comment: There's `purrr:map_depth`, but you have to also provide the names, which there doesn't seem to be a convenient function for.

Comment: I am also looking at `rapply`, but it seems to be more for applying function on elements of a certain class.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `rrapply` in the `rrapply`-package (extended version of base `rapply`), which might be easier to generalize to arbitrarily nested lists:

```r
library(rrapply)

rrapply(
  lst, 
  f = function(x, .xpos) paste(names(lst)[.xpos[1]], names(lst[[.xpos[1]]])[.xpos[2]], sep = "///")
)
#> $A1
#> $A1$Level2
#> $A1$Level2$Level3
#> [1] "A1///Level2"
#> 
#> 
#> 
#> $B1
#> $B1$Level2
#> $B1$Level2$Level3
#> [1] "B1///Level2"
```

Here, the `.xpos` variable evaluates to the position in the nested list of the current node under evaluation, so this information can be used to retrieve the names of all ancestor nodes.

Note that for the returned result, the default is `how = "replace"`, which will keep the original list structure, (in base `rapply` the default is `how = "unlist"`).